# Application Verifier Debug Extensions

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, heap-corruption, application-verifier

I'm writing a Windows C++ program in Visual Studio 2010 and have heap corruption. The !heap and !avrf debugger extensions from Application Verifier have several tools that sound quite useful for tracking this down, however I am unclear as to how to effectively use Application Verifier. For instance, Application Verifier documentation states:

> You can use `!avrf -hp -a Address` to display all heap space operations that affected the specified Address.

Where exactly does one type this command? (Yes, I know Address needs to be replaced by an actual address.) Does it need to be prefixed by anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Windows debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852360) command. You can see the help for the [command here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff562138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there no way to use some window in MSVS2010 IDE?

Comment: @Adrian not that I know of.